# XML Serializer does but Json Serializer doesn't Serialize Action method return type

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on webApi 2, where i use EF 6 (DB-First) as Data-Access. 
I have so many entities on my *.edmx file and i want to use them as return types of my webApi methods.

when i use default settings, outputs are serialized by XML Serializer, but when i change default serializer to Json Serializer by adding these lines (into  `WebApiConfig.cs`):

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

it just returns `Id : "1"`. i tried these lines also :

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
 json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
 json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
 config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

it has the same results. 
the only workable approach for me was to use `JavaScriptSerializer`. but it makes my WebApi unpredictable for other developers, because it just returns `String` values. I'm using `JavaScriptSerializer` in this way :

```
 public string Method(){
 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 // ....
 return js.Serialize(Datas);}
```

is there any applicable approach to automatically serialize EF Object into Json in WebApi 2 ?

Comment: How is it unpredicatable for other developers? If you are converting to JSON, it's going to return the value as a string which needs to be desiarilized.

Comment: I have a `BusinessContract` layer which keeps WebApi Interfaces. 
I have another project which uses `restSharp` to send/receive requests/Response to and from WebApi. So I'm able to use this project as WebApi Client to get ride of challenging with WebApi.
`BusinessContract` is the heart of my BusinessLayer and it's design plays an important role to development Costs. 
for example : if i had so many subEntities that comes from `User` entity, it takes time to find right model to Deserialize incoming `Json string`

Comment: Why not just add a base property to your classes which identifies which type to use for desiarilization?

Comment: Base Property ? did you mean `Attributes` ? it has some over head after all, where it has a silly problem in automatic serialization, it's a reasonable deal to pay more time to resolve this.

Comment: I was assuming you have many classes representing your User entity and subEntities, I was referring to making an abstract class or interface which all these classes either inherit or implement with a Property indicating the type needed for deserialization. Then you just populate that property on your API before sending it back and your client can then desiarilize based on that property to determine the type.

Comment: thanks, it's a good idea. but i'm still search for the main problem.

Comment: Ok. Good luck sir.

Answer (score 0):

> GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
>    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

These two lines explicitly means that whatever your Web API is sending in response ,it would be always in Json Format Type.

> it just returns Id : "1"

Why it wont ? its a valid Json.

> json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
>    json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

These two are irrelevant in the current context.

> I'm using JavaScriptSerializer in this way :

Serialize will always give you nothing but a string.

> is there any applicable approach to automatically serialize EF Object into Json in WebApi 2 ?

Make your return Type as EF Object Type.and let the WEB API media type formatter as Json. Or let the return type Dynamic if you dont want to specify and in the body return any kind of Object you want.Web API will give you as Json format

Comment: Id : "1" is valid but correct output is : "[{"ID":1,"FirstName":"Reza","LastName":"Noei","Email":null,"UserName":"Reza","Password":"12225","DiskUsed":null,"DiskUsage":1000,"Status":null,"Telephone":null,"Mobile":null,"Skype":null,"IM":null,"GoogleUserName":null,"CompanyName":"Chert","CompanyAddress":"","CompanyTelephone":"092225","CompanyFax":"","CompanyEmail":"","ContentLikes":[],"ContentPermission":[],"File":[],"FolderPermission":[],"SiteUsers":[],"UserGroup":[]}]"

Comment: `Serialize will always give you nothing but a string.` => Please read my comments on `Ryan` I'm searching for the best not the first

Comment: `Make your return Type as EF Object Type.and let the WEB API media type formatter as Json` I have already done that but webApi isn't able to serialize my Objects. it just returns `Id : "1"`

Comment: Can you edit your question with the action method return type and its Class structure.